# 2nd order ODE: $xy''+(x-1)y'-y=x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve:
>    $xy''+(x-1)y'-y=x^2$ .

I am not able to find an elegant method to find the solution. Therefore, I proceeded in following way- First I observed that $y=x-1$ is the solution of homogenous part. I then transformed the problem as $y \to (x-1)v$ and solved the simplified ODE to get $y=e^{-(x-1)}$ as the second solution of homogenous part.

I then applied the method of variation of parameters and obtained the solutions as $$ y_1= x(x-1) ; y_2= -(x-2)$$

However, $y_2$ doesn't really solve the original ODE. My question- Is there a better method to solve this DE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differential equation can be written as:

$$x(y^{"}+y^{'})-(y+y^{'})=x^2$$

Take $u=y+y^{'}$ therefore:

$$xu^{'}-u=x^2$$

or

$$({u\over x})^{'}=1$$

which leads to $$u=x^2+C_1x$$

where $C_1$ is a constant. So we have:

$$y+y^{'}=x^2+C_1x$$

let $y=e^{-x}w$ then $y+y^{'}=e^{-x}w-e^{-x}w+e^{-x}w^{'}=e^{-x}w^{'}$ and by substitution:

$$w^{'}=(x^2+Cx)e^{x}\to w=((x-1)^2+C_1(x-1)+1)e^x+C_2$$

therefore

$$y=x^2-2x+2+C_1(x-1)+C_2e^{-x}$$

Comment: note that $-2x+2=-2(x-1)$ hence $-2x+2+C_1(x-1)=-2(x-1)+C_1(x-1)=(C_1-2)(x-1)=C_3(x-1)$ so we left with $x^2+C_3(x-1)+C_2e^{-x}$